# AWS lambda function to retrieve favicon url of a web site only gets partial html using node.js request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm trying to create an Amazon Web Services lambda function that will return the url of the favicon of a website.

The lambda function uses 2 node.js modules:
1) request
2) cheerio

As a test case, I used: event = { "url": "www.github.com" }.

The code doesn't fail to execute, but it only seems to gather part of the html of the website and returns an empty string ("") instead of the favicon url for GitHub's website.

Here is the code for index.js:

```js
'use strict';

const request = require("node_modules/request");
const cheerio = require("node_modules/cheerio");
var faviconUrl = "";

console.log('Loading lambda function');

function getFaviconUrl(url){
    var urlParts = url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/);
    var domain = "https://" + urlParts[0];
    var options = {
        url: domain,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html"
        }
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, html){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            console.log(html);
            $("link", "head", html).each(function(i, element){
                console.log(element);
                const rel = $(element).attr("rel");
                if (rel === "icon" || rel === "shortcut icon" || rel === "fluid-icon") {
                  faviconUrl = $(element).attr("href");
                  return false;
                }
            });
            if (faviconUrl.indexOf("/") === 0) { // If path returned is relative
                faviconUrl = "https://" + domain + faviconUrl;
            }
        }
    });
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    getFaviconUrl(event.url);
    callback(null, faviconUrl)
}
```

and here is the result displayed in the Lambda Management Console:

```html
</div>
  </div>
</div>




  <div id="ajax-error-message" class="ajax-error-message flash flash-error">
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-alert" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.865 1.52c-.18-.31-.51-.5-.87-.5s-.69.19-.87.5L.275 13.5c-.18.31-.18.69 0 1 .19.31.52.5.87.5h13.7c.36 0 .69-.19.86-.5.17-.31.18-.69.01-1L8.865 1.52zM8.995 13h-2v-2h2v2zm0-3h-2V6h2v4z"/></svg>
    <button type="button" class="flash-close js-flash-close js-ajax-error-dismiss" aria-label="Dismiss error">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-x" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 12 16" width="12"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.48 8l3.75 3.75-1.48 1.48L6 9.48l-3.75 3.75-1.48-1.48L4.52 8 .77 4.25l1.48-1.48L6 6.52l3.75-3.75 1.48 1.48z"/></svg>
    </button>
    You can't perform that action at this time.
  </div>


    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/compat-91f98c37fc84eac24836eec2567e9912742094369a04c4eba6e3cd1fa18902d9.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-4b1b3e45ebb896ec5555a60b6a57072c698f1b4b86b76aa0b4fe1067f440b1f3.js"></script>
    
    <script async="async" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-ae14d253dbc91b402aece489d3993239e510fd1c15fc805402943b552f315d73.js"></script>
    
    
    
    
  <div class="js-stale-session-flash stale-session-flash flash flash-warn flash-banner d-none">
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-alert" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.865 1.52c-.18-.31-.51-.5-.87-.5s-.69.19-.87.5L.275 13.5c-.18.31-.18.69 0 1 .19.31.52.5.87.5h13.7c.36 0 .69-.19.86-.5.17-.31.18-.69.01-1L8.865 1.52zM8.995 13h-2v-2h2v2zm0-3h-2V6h2v4z"/></svg>
    <span class="signed-in-tab-flash">You signed in with another tab or window. <a href="">Reload</a> to refresh your session.</span>
    <span class="signed-out-tab-flash">You signed out in another tab or window. <a href="">Reload</a> to refresh your session.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="facebox" id="facebox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="facebox-popup">
    <div class="facebox-content" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="facebox-header" aria-describedby="facebox-description">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="facebox-close js-facebox-close" aria-label="Close modal">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-x" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 12 16" width="12"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.48 8l3.75 3.75-1.48 1.48L6 9.48l-3.75 3.75-1.48-1.48L4.52 8 .77 4.25l1.48-1.48L6 6.52l3.75-3.75 1.48 1.48z"/></svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? It looks to me like this is an async issue – your callback will fire as soon as the HTTP request begins, not when it finishes. You need to call your callback inside the success callback of the HTTP request.

Comment: For the mean time, I'm simply testing by clicking the Test button in the Lambda Management Console. If I place callback in the request section then it's out of scope! I don't know how to trigger the callback after the request has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your callback fire when the `request()` call is done.

Change your `exports.handler` so it passes your callback to the asynchronous function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    getFaviconUrl(event.url, callback);
}
```

... and then in your `getFaviconUrl()` function, trigger the callback after `faviconUrl` has been set. This should mean your callback function only executes once the favicon has been set to something.

Comment: Turns out that I was retrieving the entire HTML, but the Lambda Management Console on shows part of the logs! One had to click on the entire CloudWatch log group to see the entire logs!

Comment: There also was an error in the way I was extracting the links from the HTML. Anyway, your advice regarding where to place the callback did the trick! It's finally working. Thanks a bunch Matt!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: The working version of index.js may be found here: https://github.com/odebroqueville/getFaviconUrl

Comment: Cool – for what it's worth, you can use `npm` to install your dependencies and store them in a `package.json` file, then you don't need to commit the (huge) `node_modules` directory, and in your code you can just write `require('request')` and it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Matt.